# Linq returning 1 record

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
var q = from Blog in db.tblBlogEntries where Blog.ID == EntryID select Blog;
```

This will return one record only, as Blog.ID is a primary key.

How do I then:

- Check something was returned (EOF)
- Access the data returned without a foreach loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `SingleOrDefault()` extension. Make sure you check for null.

```
var q = (from Blog in db.tblBlogEntries where Blog.ID == EntryID select Blog).SingleOrDefault();

if( q != null)
{


}
```

Comment: If you select by ID you probably want to use Single() as you always expect something back. Single throws an Exception if nothing fullfils the where criteria.

Answer (score 3):

```
var data = q.FirstOrDefault(); // Or use SingleOrDefault if you want it to throw an error when the result has more than one element.
if (data == null ) 
    // Your query did not match any elements
else
    // The result element is in data variable.
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181753/linq-var-and-typed-object/5181856#5181856) concerning retrieving one element from a Linq query.

(I think you'll want to use the `SingleOrDefault` method.)